# AssertionError: Cannot specify FastAPI annotation for BackgroundTasks

Tags: fastapi

Lets consider a simple FastAPI app,

```py
# main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Query, BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root(background_tasks : BackgroundTasks = Query(default=None, include_in_schema=False)):
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

It works fine on `fastapi==0.82.0`

But when I upgrade the version to `fastapi==0.109.1`,
I get an `AssertionError: Cannot specify FastAPI annotation for type <class 'fastapi.background.BackgroundTasks'>`

Additionally, On the newer version,

```py
@app.get("/")
def read_root(api_call = Query(default=None, include_in_schema=False)):
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

is a working code.

```py
@app.get("/")
def read_root(background_tasks : BackgroundTasks = None):
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}
```

is also a working code.

Somehow I can't assign `Query(default=None, include_in_schema=False)` to `BackgroundTasks`

I was trying to upgrade the version of FastAPI on an year old repository.
It contains the line `background_tasks : BackgroundTasks = Query(default=None, include_in_schema=False)` which is incompatible with the new version of FastAPI.

Comment: What do you expect assigning a query value to a background task object should do? That seems to be broken in any case; you probably want to assign it to a type that matches string, and then create a background task through the `background_tasks` that gets set up when the controller gets called?